# Best practice for paths defined in cross platform config files

Tags: node.js, winapi, configuration, path, posix

I'm building a node application that has config files that are to be edited by users of the application, and they have file paths in them.

These config files will be used in Windows, Linux and MacOSX. For example, a project using this application might be developed in both Windows and MacOSX, but the config files are the same.

What is the best practice for the format of the paths in this case?

I have a couple of possibilities:

- Force POSIX for the config files, and then when handling them, convert them to the current platform. The problem here is that Windows users might not like to have paths in the different format that they are used to.
- Allow both formats in the config files and when parsing, convert them to the current platform. I'm afraid this might lead to issues parsing. Also, it might lead to weird mixed config files.

I think there's a lot of software out there that had the same dilemma, so I'm wondering if there's some best practice out there.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: paths are only going to be relative, no absolute paths. If someone puts an absolute path, then that config can't be used in different OSs anyway, so it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Converting between `/` and `\` on the fly should not be a big issue, dealing with the root of the path is where things get problematic.

I would suggest that you add support for some kind of string expansion so that users can specify paths relative to known locations. Something like this perhaps:

```
imagedir=%config%/myimages
fallbackimagedir=%appdir%/images
```

You should also try to deal with full paths.

I would suggest that you convert Windows drive letter paths like `c:\foo` to `/c/foo` when reading the config on POSIX systems. This is easy since the string length is the same but it does assume that `/c` has been set up to be something useful.

Reading a POSIX path on Windows is trickier, when given a path that begins with `/` you have to prefix it with something. What that something is, is up to you, perhaps the drive letter root of the drive where your application is installed.

Comment: Actually, I will most likely not have absolute paths, they will all be relative to the project. Since this is supposed to be used in different OSs, it won't make sense unless I use string expansion as you suggested. I'll update my question to reflect that, as probably it simplifies things. Thank you for your answer nonetheless, it's informative and on topic :)